# VBA - Function works, but Excel crashes

Tags: excel, vba

I have such function to match data between two sheets. In Tab there is only a few rows that need to get ID number from sheet Dan which contains about 10 000 IDs.

```
Sub MatchName()
Dim n1 As Long
Dim n2 As Long

 Dim LastRowcheck1 As Long
 Dim LastRowcheck2 As Long
 
LastRowcheck1 = Sheets("Tab").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowcheck2 = Sheets("Dan").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Tab").Activate
 For n1 = 2 To LastRowcheck1
   For n2 = 2 To LastRowcheck2
        Debug.Print "From: " & Sheets("Dan").Cells(n2, 1).Value & " to " & Sheets("Tab").Cells(n1, 3).Value
        If Sheets("Tab").Cells(n1, 3).Value = Sheets("Dan").Cells(n2, 1).Value Then
            Sheets("Tab").Cells(n1, 6).Value = Sheets("Dan").Cells(n2, 1).Value
            Sheets("Tab").Cells(n1, 30).Value = Sheets("Dan").Cells(n2, 2).Value
        End If
    Next n2
  Next n1
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel crashes - what do You mean? Randomly close the workbook, vba error or..?

Comment: When you need to compare a large amount of data between sheets, it is very inefficient to use nested loops to find matching values. To quickly compare data, it is better to use  [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) and/or `Application.Match()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 2 loops.

Loop through the relevant column on one of the sheets and use `Application.Match` to find if there's a match in the relevant column on the other sheet.

If there is a match copy the data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MatchName()
Dim n1 As Long
Dim LastRowcheck1 As Long
Dim Res As Variant
 
    LastRowcheck1 = Sheets("Tab").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For n1 = 2 To LastRowcheck1
    
        Res = Application.Match(Sheets("Tab").Cells(n1, 3), Sheets("Dan").Columns(1), 0)
        
        If Not IsError(Res) Then
            
            Sheets("Tab").Cells(n1, 6).Value = Sheets("Dan").Cells(Res, 1).Value
            Sheets("Tab").Cells(n1, 30).Value = Sheets("Dan").Cells(Res, 2).Value
        End If
        
    Next n1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked for entire data set. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Excel tends to freeze when a macro takes too long. Even if 'Tab' only contains 10 rows that's still 100000 loops.

The [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) function prevents that freeze. Make sure to include it in a way that it occurs every once in a while (like every 1000 loops). You can also include it in every loop, but it might slow things down (that's a guess on my part).

Be aware that it will likely still take a long time for that subroutine to run through. Here's two ways to quicken it, so you might not even need DoEvents:

1. When that If condition is true you are basicially done with the n2 loop, if I understood things correctly. Use 'Exit For' to end the n2 loop prematurely, as there's no need to check the remaining up to 9999 rows.
2. Find a way to sort your 'Dan' data so that they are in the same order as the 'Tab' data. Depending on your data it might be that after you found a match for n1= 2 in for example n2=1000 you don't have to start over from n2=2 for n1=3, because you already know the match won't be in the first 1000 entries. So you can start the loop not from n2=2 but from n2=1000. You'd have to store the value of n2 in a variable when exiting the loop as described in 1) or creature a custom For loop using Do Until. But that depends on the kind of data you have. It might drasticially reduce the amount of loops you need though.

Comment: They can't be sorted. The goal is to match 99 000 data names in Tab with ID number from DAN which contains 10 000 different IDs types for the names. In worst situation there will be about 100 million loops...Would be great if Excel could handle so enormous amount of data.